# Why does Utf8Helper::setCollatorLanguage always return false?

Tags: arangodb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnyrP.png)Why does the fuction `Utf8Helper::setCollatorLanguage` in arangodb sdk always return false?

It is at fault ERROR ERROR in the Collator: : createInstance < > : U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR；And It's lead to failed to initialise ICU; ICU_DATA= "F:\\work_lc\\arangodb-2.6\\Build32\\bin\\..\\\\share\\arangodb\\";This project where to copy from others, it can be used, but i'm not,I just wonder what configuration file not produced

Comment: Reworded to make it a little clearer

Comment: When using arangodb source code, to run the program, including the setCollatorLanguage function always returns false (found the reason is because the Collator: : createInstance has not been successful, this function is inside the lib).

Comment: Now just want to know why it create instance has not been successful

Comment: Please add more details to the question by editing it, including what the error messages are, in order to help others answer your question.

Comment: can you specify this a bit deeper? `bin/arangod --console /tmp/2093875423 --default-language cn -c etc/relative/arangod.conf` works for me? Its depending on the propper setup of ICU.

Comment: It is at fault ERROR ERROR in the Collator: : createInstance < > : U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR；And It's lead to failed to initialise ICU; ICU_DATA= "F:\\\\work_lc\\\\arangodb-2.6\\\\Build32\\\\bin\\\\..\\\\\\\\share\\\\arangodb\\\\";This project where to copy from others, it can be used, but i'm not,I just wonder what configuration file not produced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make shure, ICU is able to load its locale database.

See [our cookbook regarding windows compilation](https://docs.arangodb.com/cookbook/Compiling/Windows30.html#making-the-icu-database-pulically-available) how to achieve this.

Please note that ArangoDB 2.6 is way out of date, and you should work with a more recent version.

More recent versions will also provide better error messages in such situations via the windows event log.

Comment: Thank you very much, my problem is solved, is that there is no correct loaded into the database language environment.THANKS

Comment: I want to ask, ICU is a database?Or what other, feel it let me have a little confused